# Italicizing the main word but not the subscripted word

Tags: r, plot, plotmath

I was wondering how to **only** make the main word `d` in my `text()` to appear in italic, but the subscripted word `"unbiased"` to remain as ordinary text?

Please see my R code below the following picture.

[image]

Here is my R code:

```
plot(1:10, ty="n")

text( 4, 4.5, bquote(italic(d[(unbiased)])), cex = 5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the "unbiased" outside `italic` or use `plain`:

```
plot(1:10, ty = "n")
# original
text(5, 4, bquote(italic(d[(unbiased)])), cex = 5)
# use plain
text(5, 6, bquote(italic(d[(plain(unbiased))])), cex = 5)
# keep "unbiased" outside italic
text(5, 8, bquote(italic(d)[(unbiased)]), cex = 5)
```

[image]